# How do I remove html tags in a list created with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So I scraped different titles from a Wikipedia page, for example:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun

I scraped all the mw-headlines

```
titles = soup.find_all('span', {"class":"mw-headline"})
```

Now I want to make a list of the titles and print them

```
print(list(titles))
```

My result is a list with all the html code

```
[<span class="mw-headline" id="Name_and_etymology">Name and etymology</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="General_characteristics">General characteristics</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Sunlight">Sunlight</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Composition">Composition</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Singly_ionized_iron-group_elements">Singly ionized iron-group elements</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Isotopic_composition">Isotopic composition</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Structure_and_fusion">Structure and fusion</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Core">Core</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Radiative_zone">Radiative zone</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Tachocline">Tachocline</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Convective_zone">Convective zone</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Photosphere">Photosphere</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Atmosphere">Atmosphere</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Photons_and_neutrinos">Photons and neutrinos</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Magnetic_activity">Magnetic activity</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Magnetic_field">Magnetic field</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Variation_in_activity">Variation in activity</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Long-term_change">Long-term change</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Life_phases">Life phases</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Formation">Formation</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Main_sequence">Main sequence</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="After_core_hydrogen_exhaustion">After core hydrogen exhaustion</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Orbit_and_location">Orbit and location</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Orbit_in_Milky_Way">Orbit in Milky Way</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Theoretical_problems">Theoretical problems</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Coronal_heating_problem">Coronal heating problem</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Faint_young_Sun_problem">Faint young Sun problem</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Observational_history">Observational history</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Early_understanding">Early understanding</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Development_of_scientific_understanding">Development of scientific understanding</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Solar_space_missions">Solar space missions</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Observation_and_effects">Observation and effects</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Planetary_system">Planetary system</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Religious_aspects">Religious aspects</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="See_also">See also</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Notes">Notes</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="References">References</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="Further_reading">Further reading</span>, <span class="mw-headline" id="External_links">External links</span>]
```

How do I remove the tags so I just have a list with all the titles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than converting the `titles` iterable to a list, you can iterate over them and take the text element using the `text` attribute on the tag:

```
titles = [tag.text for tag in soup.find_all('span', {"class":"mw-headline"})]
```

Comment: This worked, but how do I put them in 1 list? I now have a bunch of lines with titles.

Comment: @snocc `titles` is a `list`;  i've used list comprehension here. Check `type(titles)`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. I copied only one bracket and had an error so I deleted it. Thanks for helping